# Modifying vendor embedded libraries in a way that facilitates vendor library updates?

Tags: c, embedded, firmware

I am working on a C embedded firmware project that utilizes libraries provided by the vendor.  For example, a TCP/IP stack library.  The vendor regularly updates these libraries.  However, we have made many additions and customizations to the libraries for our specific application.

In some cases, previous designers have taken a library source file, modified it, then renamed it and moved it to a different folder in the source.  This seems problematic, as it makes it more difficult to track the file and apply vendor library updates.

What are some best-practices to this scenario?  In other words, would it be feasible to separate the customizations from the original library source files?  And what are some successful approaches to this?

Comment: I tend to prefer keeping a library as a library. Compile the vendor's source separately and then link against it in your code. Unless you need to modify the library in which case you might want to consider patch queues or something similar (making your work a lot harder) but still keeping the code as a separate library.

Comment: The idea of [patch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) is used by RPM and others to deal with *pristine* source and small changes that need to be made.  The idea of patching is built into RPM.  This is always a balance against the extent of the patches.  Another way is to give the patches to the vendor so they can incorporate them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use separate the library files from your project. I would recommend using version control (Mercurial, Git or similar) to manage updates:

1. Make repo and commit original vendor libs (branch **A**).
2. Take your changes and commit them to a branch **B** (**B** starts from **A**).
3. When ever you modify your library further, edit sources in branch **B** and commit changes.
4. If vendor makes updates, commit them to branch **A**, and then merge the head of **A** to the head of **B**.
5. When you are ready, either copy latest files from branch **B** to your main project, or compile it as library which you can link to your main project.

Then your history might look something like this:

```
A1 ------- A2
  \          \
   B1 - B2 -- B3 - B4
```

Where:

- `A1` is the original vendor lib
- `A2` is the updated vendor lib
- `B1`, `B2` and `B4` are your changes
- `B3` is where changes of the vendor are merged to your changes.